# how to solve "File not found or corrupted" when using pytotch to download an image set?

Tags: python, pytorch, imageset

here is my code:

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torch.utils import data
from torchvision import transforms
trans = transforms.ToTensor()
mnist_train = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(root='../data', train=True, transform=trans, download=True)
mnist_test = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(root='../data', train=False, transform=trans, download=True)
```

When I try to download the data set, I always encounter such an error after running the code。 I searched various methods on the Internet, but still can't solve this problem

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/ds_ghr/code/DL/train.ipynb Cell 22 in ()
      1 trans = transforms.ToTensor()
----> 2 mnist_train = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(root='../data', train=True, transform=trans, download=True)
      3 mnist_test = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(root='../data', train=False, transform=trans, download=True)
      4 len(mnist_train), len(mnist_test)

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/mnist.py:99, in MNIST.__init__(self, root, train, transform, target_transform, download)
     96     return
     98 if download:
---> 99     self.download()
    101 if not self._check_exists():
    102     raise RuntimeError("Dataset not found. You can use download=True to download it")

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/mnist.py:187, in MNIST.download(self)
    185 try:
    186     print(f"Downloading {url}")
--> 187     download_and_extract_archive(url, download_root=self.raw_folder, filename=filename, md5=md5)
    188 except URLError as error:
    189     print(f"Failed to download (trying next):\n{error}")

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/utils.py:434, in download_and_extract_archive(url, download_root, extract_root, filename, md5, remove_finished)
    431 if not filename:
    432     filename = os.path.basename(url)
...
    153 # check integrity of downloaded file
    154 if not check_integrity(fpath, md5):
--> 155     raise RuntimeError("File not found or corrupted.")

RuntimeError: File not found or corrupted.
```

here is my environment:
python version: 3.9
pytorch 2.0.1

Comment: i tried your code in colab, works fine for me

Comment: do you have an access to download files into that folder?

Comment: Don't know what the problem is. Works fine when I ran the program on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

```
import torch
import torchvision
from torch.utils import data
from torchvision import transforms
trans = transforms.ToTensor()
mnist_train = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(root='../data', train=True, transform=trans, download=True)
mnist_test = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(root='../data', train=False, transform=trans, download=True)
```

Run this in https://colab.research.google.com/. And then download it from Colab. This works for me.